# How many zeroes at the end of $3^34^45^56^6 - 3^64^55^46^3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gre-exam

The quantity $3^34^45^56^6 - 3^64^55^46^3$ will end in how many zeros?

This is a GRE Practice question and I have to do it without using a calculator. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It is a good thing that it is without calculator, the GRE has lots of questions, and a calculator would slow one down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using $a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}; a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$ and $(a\cdot b)^m=a^m\cdot b^m$ where $a,b,m$ are real numbers

$$3^34^45^56^6 - 3^64^55^46^3$$

$$=3^3(2^2)^45^5(2\cdot3)^6 - 3^6(2^2)^55^4(2\cdot3)^3$$

$$= 2^{8+6}5^53^{6+3} - 3^{3+6}2^{10+3}5^4$$

$$=2^{13}5^43^9(2\cdot5-1)$$

As $10=2\cdot5,$ the highest power of $10$ will be min $(13,4)$

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Factor and simplify.

Step 2: Only powers of 2, 5 are relevant in answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

## S = $3^34^45^56^6 - 3^64^55^46^3$

=$\underbrace{3^32^36^6(5*2)^5}_{\mathcal A}   - \underbrace{  3^62^66^3(5*2)^4}_{\mathcal B}$

So we see above that  both A and B have ( unequal number of )trailing zeroes. A has 5 Zeroes while B has 4 at its end.
 In this case for S= A-B...

> **number of zeroes at the end of  S** will be  the number of  zeroes at the end of of the lesser of the two numbers amongst A and B  viz **4**

as *the fifth digit of S is going to be non zero ( substraction of a non zero digit of B from zero; the fifth trailing zero of A)*

EDIT: In response to the query by OP; the logic remains same in case of addition so A+B again will have 4 zeros

Comment: You could have made this shorter by just saying "$3^3 4^4 5^5 6^6$ has $5$ zeroes while $3^6 4^5 5^4 6^3$ has $4$ zeroes so their difference has $4$ zeroes"

Comment: That would be fast enough for GRE

Comment: @ARi What if the question involved addition instead of subtraction of the two terms? Then would the answer be 5?

Comment: It will still be 4

Comment: In fact this is the shortest solution

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$3^34^45^56^6-3^64^55^46^3=5^4(3^34^45^16^6-3^64^56^3)$$

There are always enough factors of $2$ to match the powers of $5$ to give at least four zeros - but the term in brackets cannot be by $5$. This is because $5$  divides the first product in the brackets, but not the second, so cannot divide their difference.